# Micronaut Constraint Validation

Tags: micronaut

In grails it is simple to write custom validation and cross field validation.

How can this be done within the micronaut framework?

Given a simple POJO which contains a list of complex objects;

a) How can a validator be written to ensure uniqueness in the list?

b) How can a validator be written when there is some relationship between the fields?

When using a class that implements io.micronaut.validation.validator.constraints.ConstraintValidator - it only seems possible to access the value of the annotated field itself.

````
package pkg;

import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Introspected;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@Introspected
public class PoJo {

    // how to write a validation to check for uniqueness in the list, e.g. only one on each type exists in the list
    @Valid
    List<ComplexObject> complexObjectList;

    public PoJo(List<ComplexObject> complexObjectList) {
        this.complexObjectList = complexObjectList;
    }

    public List<ComplexObject> getComplexObjectList() {
        return complexObjectList;
    }
}


package pkg;

import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Introspected;

@Introspected
public class ComplexObject {

    // how to cross validate fields
    // e.g. type=A num must be > 0 and < 10
    //      type=B num must be > 10 and < 20
    String type;
    int num;

    public ComplexObject(String type, int num) {
        this.type = type;
        this.num = num;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

> a) How can a validator be written to ensure uniqueness in the list?

There are many ways this could be done. One option is creating a Set and comparing the size to the original.

> b) How can a validator be written when there is some relationship between the fields?

Apply the validator to the object that contains both fields